# Adding a single percentage label to bar chart: ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've taken a look at other questions similar that mention `geom_text`. However, my question is a bit different. I have a bar chart where the second bar is constructed based on the first bar for each category.

Here's the data:

```
structure(list(source = c("College Provided", "College Provided", 
"Corporate", "Corporate", "Course Production", "Course Production"
), divided_column = c(36.8421052631579, 36.8421052631579, 50, 
50, 75.609756097561, 75.609756097561), number_of_courses = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), levels = c("Total Courses", "Courses With Issues"
), class = "factor"), value = c(19L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 41L, 31L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

[image: The divided column calculates a percentage which divides courses with issues by total courses]

When I use `geom_text`, it labels *both the bars.* I want the percentage only on the second bar.

```
ggplot(total_courses_issues_long,  
       aes(x = fct_infreq(source), y = value, fill = number_of_courses)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = 0.6) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(divided_column, 2), "%")), 
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), 
            vjust = -0.5, size = 3)
```

[image: Constructed Graph]

I only want the percentage value on the second bar. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option would be to map the condition directly on the `label` aes in `geom_text` where additionally I use `scales::percent` to format as percentages and also aligned the labels with the bars using `position_dodge(width = 0.6)`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)

ggplot(
  total_courses_issues_long,
  aes(
    x = fct_infreq(source),
    y = value,
    fill = number_of_courses
  )
) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge", width = 0.6) +
  geom_text(
    aes(label = ifelse(
      number_of_courses %in% "Courses With Issues",
      scales::percent(divided_column, accuracy = .1, scale = 1),
      ""
    )),
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.6),
    vjust = -0.5, size = 3
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could pre-process the labels to desired output prior to running ggplot. And centre the labels by making the width arguments of the call to `position_dodge` the same.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)
library(dplyr)

total_courses_issues_long |> 
  mutate(divided_column = ifelse(row_number() %% 2 == 0,
                                 paste0(round(divided_column, 2), "%"),
                                 "")) |> 
ggplot(aes(x = fct_infreq(source), y = value, fill = number_of_courses)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = 0.8) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = divided_column), 
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.8), 
            vjust = -0.5, size = 3)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-07-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>